# Chrome PDF Reader Renders colors wrong, while other PDF browsers work

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, colors

I recently made a website that hosts PDFs of scans of a publication. For some reason the Chrome PDF viewer renders the PDFs in magenta, while other browsers render them correctly. I've seen lots of posts about how Chrome renders colors as more saturated, but can't locate anything else on the same subject.

In Safari:

[image]

In Chrome:

[image]

Comment: The built-in viewer in chrome is far from perfect. But without the PDF itself it is hard to tell.

Comment: thanks, the link is https://s3.amazonaws.com/BWARCHIVE/1999/1999-3.pdf

Comment: I have a hunch it has something to do with http headers because the same file served from www.columbia.edu/cu/bw/PDFS/Blue and White Archives/2000/March 2000.pdf renders fine in chrome itself

Comment: I'm not exactly sure where this question is more appropriate but SO isn't the right place for it, even though it's not a bad question. Perhaps try http://superuser.com?

Comment: I'll check it later in office, but have you already tried opening that file from disc in chrome?

Comment: I just opened that URL in Chrome (Version 36.0.1985.125 m on Win7/64bit) and it looked all right. If the issue is Chrome-related, it seems to occur in certain versions only.

Comment: my apologies if I've put this in the wrong place. Thanks for everyone's help so far though!

Answer (score 0):

There appears to a bug in the Chrome PDF viewer (possibly only on OSX): https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=401118